# Assigning to vs. from a slice

Tags: python, slice, idioms

When reading `profile.py` of python standard library I came across the assignment statement `sys.argv[:] = args`, which is used to modify `sys.argv` to make the program being profiled see the correct command line arguments.  I understand that this is different from `sys.argv = args[:]` in the actual operations, but **in effect** they look the same to me.  Is there a situation when one wants to use one and not the other?  And is `a[:] = b` a common python idiom?

UPDATE: in this specific situation why would one choose one over the other?  (source can be found in the `main` function of `profile.py`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is, when you use `a[:] = b` it means you will override whatever is already on `a`. If you have something else with a reference to `a` it will change as well, as it keeps referencing the same location.

In the other hand, `a = b[:]` creates a new reference and copy all the values from `b` to this new reference. So existing references to the old data will keep pointing to the old data.

Consider this example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> c = a # c is a reference to the list in a
>>> c
[1, 2, 3]
>>> 
>>> a[:] = b
>>> a # a will have a copy of the list in b
[4, 5, 6] 
>>> c # and c will keep having the same value as a
[4, 5, 6]
>>>
>>> b = [7, 8, 9]
>>> a = b[:]
>>> a # a has the new value
[7, 8, 9]
>>> c # c keeps having the old value
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you, I realized that this makes a difference if there are other references to `a`

Comment: Might be helpful to give an example. If `x = [1, 2, 3]`, and `a = x` (so they reference the same list), doing `a = b[:]` replaces the _reference_ in `a` with a copy of `b`; `x` is unchanged. On the other hand, `a[:] = b` replaces the _contents_ of `a` (whose reference is unchanged) with the values from `b`, which means `x` is also modified; the reference linkage was never broken.

Comment: I edited to add more details. But an example should be a good thing. I'll add it.

Comment: @TonyBetaLambda Does the example makes it clearer? Is there something else you need to know about it?

Comment: @HugoSadok Yes I understand the difference, but I still wish to know why the standard library chose it this way in this specific situation, as I updated the question

Comment: Uhm didn't see that. I took a look at it, it's not clear to me by looking to what is close to it. But it may be a way to assure that any preexisting reference to sys.argv will be updated with the new values.

Comment: Reassigning `sys.path` that way is mostly pointless, but the idiom is useful if you need to reassign the contents of a `list` passed as an argument to a function (modifying the caller's copy). Only `a[:] = b` will change the caller (where `a` was a function argument).

Comment: This is what makes sense to me too but the code he was talking does `sys.argv[:] = args` which should modify sys.path. I'm still not sure how effective this should be.

Comment: @ShadowRanger good point, that really makes it a useful idiom